# How to restore multiple versions of the same file of several/all borg archives

Tags: backup, borgbackup

Using borg backup, it is quite easy to restore ([extract](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.9/usage.html#borg-extract)) a specific file X from an archive to the current location `.` using

```
  $ borg extract /path/to/repo::my-files home/USERNAME/X
```

I like to extract that file from all my archives. A [single borg call](https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/discussions/7543#discussioncomment-5793223) cannot do that. How to script this so that for each of the archives (timecoded), the respective file X(timecoded) gets extracted?